# FakeItEasy Setup object is not returning in test method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, fakeiteasy

I am testing a method with **FakeItEasy** fake object. Fake object is a **MemoryStream**.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ServerClientTests
{
    private IWebClient webClient;
    private ServerClient serverClient;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        webClient = A.Fake<IWebClient>();
        serverClient = new ServerClient(webClient);

        var responseStreamBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("OK");
        var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
        responseStream.Write(responseStreamBytes, 0, responseStreamBytes.Length);
        responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var response = A.Fake<WebResponse>();
        A.CallTo(() => response.GetResponseStream()).Returns(responseStream);

        var request = A.Fake<WebRequest>();
        A.CallTo(() => request.GetResponse()).Returns(response);

        A.CallTo(() => webClient.GetRequest("http://localhost:8080/myserver")).Returns(request);

    }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var result = serverClient.GetRequest("http://localhost/myserver");

            Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Length);
      }
  }
```

And this is code under the test:

```
public interface IWebClient
{
    WebRequest GetRequest(string url);
}

public class ServerClient
{
    private readonly IWebClient client;

    public ServerClient(IWebClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Stream GetRequest(string url)
    {
        return client.GetRequest(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    }
}
```

When I run test, it gives test exception => **Expected: 2  But was:  0**

I put break point in setup method and debug test. I see that Fake request GetResponse() method returns response with stream. That **Length** is 2.

But in test method, stream **Length** is 0.

Is there any settings about FakeItEasy? Or Where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't understand "is there any settings about FakeItEasy?". If you mean documentation, you can find it at https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki, linked to from the [FakeItEasy homepage](http://fakeiteasy.github.io/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting up

```
 A.CallTo(() => webClient.GetRequest("http://localhost:8080/myserver"))
                         .Returns(request);
```

but then calling

```
serverClient.GetRequest("http://localhost/myserver");
```

So, the `webClient.GetRequest` is passed `"http://localhost/myserver"`, which doesn't match its expectation (`"http://localhost8080/myserver"`), so the `webClient` returns a fake `MemoryStream` of its own devising, with default behaviour.

You may want to make the two URLs the same. Or if you want to have your fake `webClient` be responsive to more than just the one URL, you could use more sophisticated [argument matchers](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki/Argument-Constraints).

In the future, if this sort of confusion arises over why a configured method doesn't behave the way you want, you could consider temporarily using a call to `MustHaveHappened` to check whether FakeItEasy thinks the method was called. We like to think FakeItEasy's error messages are pretty good at helping in this situation.

In your case, if you'd added a test like

```
[Test]
public void Test2()
{
    var result = serverClient.GetRequest("http://localhost/myserver");

    A.CallTo(() => webClient.GetRequest("http://localhost:8080/myserver"))
        .MustHaveHappened();
}
```

It would've said

```
Assertion failed for the following call:
  FakeItEasyQuestions.IWebClient.GetRequest("http://localhost:8080/myserver")
Expected to find it at least once but found it #0 times among the calls:
  1: FakeItEasyQuestions.IWebClient.GetRequest(url: "http://localhost/myserver")
```

Comment: But I set in constructor [serverClient = new ServerClient(webClient);] So serverClient.GetRequest() is calling webClient in class.

Comment: Ok this is my parameter issue. Thanks